# Given the $x$ and $z$ components of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ and the angle it makes with plane $xz,$ how can I find the magnitude?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The vector  $\textbf V$  has components  $5.4 i + y j + 5.3 k$ .  If  **V**  makes an angle with the $xz$-plane of $55.7$ degrees, what is its magnitude $| V |$?

That's the specific question I am working on, however I would like the steps explained so I understand the concept for future use. I am a $1$st year university student, so if possible, limit your formulas to the dot product (like $\textbf{V} \bullet \textbf{i} = |\textbf{V}| |\textbf{i}| \cos{x}$) and the simpler formulas since I'm still learning many concepts and it might fly over my head otherwise.

Currently, I am under the impression that taking the dot-product formula is what I need to be doing, but the major hangup for me is figuring out how the plane and angle need to be applied to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your vector makes an angle of $34.3^\circ$ with either the positive $y$ axis, vector $(0,1,0),$ or the negative $y$ axis, vector $(0,-1,0).$ the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $u,v$ is given by
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|} $$
Apparently
$$  \cos 34.3^\circ \approx 0.826 $$
You are considering, using the above,
$$ u = ( 5.4, y, 5.3)  $$

Answer (score 0):

We can use triangles. The distance of the leg in the $xz$-plane is $\sqrt{5.4^2+5.3^2}=\frac{\sqrt{229}}2.$

Now, since $\textbf V$ makes an angle of $55.7$ degrees in the $xz$ plane, the magnitude of $\textbf V$ will be
$$\sec{(55.7)}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{229}}2\approx13.4268380215$$

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong with your math. When I did the problem using Will Jagy's solution (or, rather, applied the principles I learned from their explanation), I got the answer 13.43. Submitting that solution through the online utility confirmed that it was the correct answer.

See if you can get the same answer, otherwise I'll have to email my prof and tell him that his online quiz is wrong!

Comment: Yup... I made a mistake... I was supposed to multiply by secant...
I was given an adjacent side is $\frac{\sqrt{229}}2$ and csc is one over sine, when I want sec which is one over cosine

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Will Jagy said, taking 34.3 degrees to be theta,⁡

$v ⃗⋅j ̂=|v ⃗ ||j ̂ |  cos⁡θ
$

$v ⃗⋅j ̂= ⁡v_y = y$

and j is a unit vector, with a magnitude of 1,

so $y = |v ⃗|cos⁡θ$

expanding that,

$y= \sqrt{y^2 + 5.4^2 + 5.3^2 }  cos⁡θ$

$y^2 = (y^2 + 57.25)  cos^2⁡ θ$

$y^2 − y^2  cos^2 ⁡θ = 57.25 cos^2⁡ θ$

$y^2 (1-cos^2 θ)$ = $57.25 cos^2⁡ θ$

$y^2 (sin^2 θ)$ = $57.25 cos^2⁡ θ$

$y^2 = \frac {57.25 cos^2⁡ θ}{sin^2 θ} $

$y^2 = \frac {52.25}{tan^2 θ} $

$y =  \frac {\sqrt{52.25}}{tan θ} $

Now that we have y, factor the formula $y = |v|cos⁡θ$ into

$ \frac {y} {cos⁡θ} = |v ⃗| $

Since $y \approx 11.09$ and $ \theta = 34.3^∘ $

$ |v ⃗| \approx 13.43 $

Hopefully all that made sense. I'm still learning how the math works (both mathematically and how to write it here), so if there's a better way to do this I'll accept any help (though, knowing how math is taught there very well may be a better way that I just haven't been taught yet).